# How can I change the default build output directory in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, build

In Visual Studio 2010 through 2013, by default (eg. When I create a new Console Application) new solutions output their compiled executable into `Solution name/Project name/bin/Debug/`. I want them to be output into `Solution name/Debug/`, and likewise for all other build configurations like "Release".

I can do this by manually going into properties of each project, going to the `Build` tab, changing `Output path` from `bin\Debug` to `..\Debug`. I must repeat this for every project and every build configuration.

After dozens of solutions, I'm a bit sick of doing this tedious task by hand every time. Is there a way to change the default output path?

A solution that works for Visual Studio 2013 is sufficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This property is defined in each [Visual Studio Project Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6db0hwky.aspx)

So, for example, the C# Console Application template is located in

```
\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\ConsoleApplication\consoleapplication.csproj
```

The csproj is an XML file that you can edit at your will. The build output directory is define like this (for each configuration):

```
...
<OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
...
<OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
...
```

If you change this file, it will change all your future new C# Console Application projects. You could also write a utility program that list all csproj in `\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates` and update them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I'm looking for - I'll try to see if it works later today (sorry for taking so long).

Comment: You really shouldn't modify the global, protected files. In fact, this may break servicing such that if the templates get updated for bug fixes or new features your modified file won't get updated. Instead you can set the `<OutputPath>` in your own .csproj and it will overwrite the global setting (if imported first). This is the recommendation within MSBuild projects.

Comment: I solved my problem by creating a new template with the output directory set as you described, thanks!

Comment: In Visual Studio 12, for example under VC/Win32, I only see a --rather void-- .VSTDIR file. Any ideas please?

Comment: I can't believe this is accepted as answer. You shouldn't mess with global templates under install dir. Please google for Directory.Build.props or Directory.Build.targets. You will find elegant way of doing this at product source code dir level.

Comment: @videoguy - This is a 10-years old answer. Don't patronize, just post your own answer

Answer (score 3):

This is not necessary.

One of the projects in your solution is marked as the Startup project, shown in bold in the Solution Explorer window.  An EXE project, like your console mode app.  You used Project + Add Reference to add references to other projects in the solution so you can use the class libraries that those projects generate in your console mode app.

Those references will have the Copy Local property set to True.

When you build your project, MSBuild will *automatically* copy the assemblies from their respective bin\Debug directory into the bin\Debug directory of your console mode app, thanks to that Copy Local setting.  And it is smart enough to also look at the dependencies of those class libraries and copy them as well.

So after the build is complete, the bin\Debug directory won't just have your console mode project's EXE file but *also* all the DLLs it needs to execute properly.

There are a few ways that this can go wrong and MSBuild cannot figure out that such a dependency actually exists.  Pretty uncommon, you'd for example have to use Reflection in your code to load assemblies (Assembly.Load() and friends).  The workaround for that is to explicitly copy the dependency in a post-build event.  You didn't leave enough bread-crumbs in your question to judge whether that's the real problem.

What you ask for is certainly possible, the IDE just doesn't make it easy because it wasn't designed to assume this was necessary at all.  You'd have to replace the Build + Output Path setting to, say, `..\Debug` instead.  You can create your own project template with that setting already preset.  Create a new class library project, change the setting and use File + Export Template to create the template.  You'll have it available the next time you create a project.

But, really, find out first why the default Copy Local machinery isn't working for you.

Comment: it makes sense to output all projects of the solution into 1 folder, it saves some time and space (think of SSDs) copying around the inner-solution-dependencies because they will only exist in the one output folder

Comment: It is just not the way MSBuild was designed.  You can fight the build system but it isn't very productive.  And no, you don't save time.  Copying build output files is a simple memory-to-memory copy, it runs at over 10 GB/sec on a modern machine.  Takes half a millisecond, you never notice it.  All hail the file system cache.  If you want to do this anyway then MSBuild won't stop you, just hassle you.

Comment: I think I phrased my question such that it presupposes that it is, in fact, necessary. To be clear, the reason I want to do this right now (I may have other reasons in the future) is that I like to feed input files into the program and produce output into a file, which means I frequently access these files while debugging and developing. I guess you would suggest that I add these files to my project, edit them from inside Visual Studio, and allow them to be copied during build - sounds like a good idea, although I'd have to think a bit on whether it would solve every issue I have.

Comment: That sounds fairly fishy.  Be sure to save data you use while debugging in the same place the user does.  Who will never store it in the same place as your build output.  Using %appdata% is pretty mandatory.

Comment: If you're code uses Dependency Inversion then this won't solve the problem. I'm working on a solution whose main project doesn't (and shouldn't) depend on some certain other project on the solution for compiling, it's the other way around, the other project depends on the main one. Yet, when running, the dll needs to be there, it's loaded dynamically.

Comment: A post-build event always solves such a problem.  That you have to write one, well, what is the big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than changing a global, protected file, you can create your own .targets file that changes the `<OutputPath>` however you want and import that into your projects. This could also set other defaults you might want to change and don't want to do for every project. All you'd have to do then in your project files is add something like toward the top (after the root element, of course):

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\Common.targets"/>
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question I believe, you still have a manual action to do (not even using the IDE). Can you explain how to automate adding that import into all your projects "by default"?